# iOS 11.3.1 doesn't connect to Apple Store if third-party certificate is deployed on the phone

Tags: ios, certificate, charles-proxy

I have iPhone device and need to test my application. However, current version of iOS does not allow to MITM the Apple Store. The rest of the user apps work fine if you follow Charles Proxy manual (install cert, add to the trusted list).

Did anyone encounter the issue before?

Answer (score 1):

iOS does allow third party certs. You just have to explicitly trust them.

Open **Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings** and enable trust for the development certificate.

This is to ensure that nobody gets an MITM cert installed on accident.

We use this all the time with iOS 11.3 with mitmproxy

Comment: that's how it's setup. All apps and browsers are working fine. Except the Apple Store, here is what I get when I try to open it https://imgur.com/a/zbyWGx1

Comment: Oh!  You're trying to proxy the Apple App Store.  Apple probably has certificate pinning in place explicitly to prevent this.